# Socket/Notification between C# and website through localhost

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets

I need to do a rare connection/notification from a C# application to a website.

Imagine, you have already opened chrome my site www.test.com, and you have opened my C# app on your desktop.

I need to notify this website in realtime when the user click in one button into the app.

The only thing I could think was, creating a socket server on the C# application listening on localhost:1234, and then when the user opens chrome and navigate to www.test.com (it's an intranet), the website connect to localhost:1234 being ready to receive the notification by socket on javascript.

I do not get to run this properly, I can connect the web to the app, but I can not send the notification to the web from the app.

Any idea? or any better way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at signalR https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
Use WebApi + SignalR you can also self host in a console